# Url Redirect after a specific server time or local time

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, time

I am attempting to have an HTML page automatically redirect to another URL on the same domain after a certain time of day.

Example:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
Date.prototype.today = function () { 
return ((this.getDate() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getDate() +"/"+(((this.getMonth()+1) < 10)?"0":"") + (this.getMonth()+1) +"/"+ this.getFullYear();
}

if((new Date().today()) >= "todaysdate 12:26PM")
{
 location.href ="http://www.google.com";
}
else
 {
 location.href="index.html";
}
if((new Date().today()) >= "todaysdate 4:26PM")
{
 location.href ="http://www.Hotmail.com";
}
else
 {
 location.href="index.html";
}
if((new Date().today()) >= "todaysdate 8:16AM")
{
 location.href ="http://www.youtube.com";
}
else
 {
 location.href="index.html";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect the page depending on the hour or is it just at a certain time? For example any day between 4pm to 5pm redirect to youtube, or you want only after 16 october redirect to youtube and before that redirect to hotmail?

Comment: daily between 4pm to 5pm redirect to example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [setHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) on new Date and compare that:

```
var time = Date.now();

if (time < new Date().setHours(12, 0, 0, 0)) { // Before 12
  location.href = "http://www.google.com";
} else if (time < new Date().setHours(16, 0, 0, 0)) { // 12 to 4pm
  location.href = "http://www.hotmail.com";
} else if (time < new Date().setHours(20, 0, 0, 0)) {  // 4pm to 8pm
  location.href = "http://www.youtube.com";
} else {
  location.href = "index.html"; // 8 pmon wards
}
```